# How to filter by date AND time in Azure DevOps/TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to see all of my test runs from a specific Date/Time.
[image: Attempt]

I can simply put a date in there and see all of the runs since a specific date, but I would like this to be more precise. I want to get all test runs with a completed date of greater than MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

What is the syntax for this? I tried putting 
    #12/12/2019 11:40:34AM#
in the box and it worked sort of. It shows all test runs for 12/12, but the time doesn't do much. If I change the AM to PM, all of the AM runs disappear, but changing the actual time value does nothing

What do I need to put in the value field to see runs by date/time?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Is UTC time working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to type the **UTC** time. For example, my time zone is UTC+08:00, if I need to filter "Completed Date > 2019-06-14 1:49:53 PM" for test runs, I would type "2019-06-14T05:49:53". Check the screenshot below:

[image]